# Android listener onDismiss doesnt work on Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

this below class is my custom dialog to show and hide dialogs, in this class i'm override onDismiss DialogFragment to hide dialogs, but in simple fragments which implemented that could not listen to that, for example this is my custom dialog:

```
public class RobotDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Bind(R.id.robot_dialog_icon)
    ImageView robot_dialog_icon;

    @Bind(R.id.frame)
    RelativeLayout frame;

    public RobotDialog() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_robot_dialog, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Window                     window       = getDialog().getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
        windowParams.dimAmount = 0.0f;
        window.setAttributes(windowParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null && activity instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {
            ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) activity).onDismiss(dialog);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
        getDialog().getWindow()
                .getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    }
}
```

and this is my simple fragment to show and must be listen to `onDismiss` on that to close dialogs:

```
public class FragmentRobotAssisstant extends Fragment implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    private TextView icon_arrow_right;
    private TextView activity_robot_title;
    private TextView icon_send_message_to_robot;

    private EditText user_chat_with_robot;

    private List<Message> mMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    private RecyclerView         mMessagesView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    private       CircularRevealView  revealView;
    private       android.os.Handler  handler;
    private       RobotDialog         robotDialog;
    private       TextView            icon_show_robot_helper;
    private       Context             context;
    private       int                 backgroundColor;
    public static OnCloseSlidingLayer onCloseSlidingLayer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_market_robot, container, false);

        context = getActivity().getBaseContext();

        //@formatter:off
        activity_robot_title        = (TextView)           view.findViewById(R.id.activity_market_robot_title);
        icon_send_message_to_robot  = (TextView)           view.findViewById(R.id.icon_send_message_to_robot);
        icon_arrow_right            = (TextView)           view.findViewById(R.id.icon_arrow_right);
        icon_show_robot_helper      = (TextView)           view.findViewById(R.id.icon_show_robot_helper);
        user_chat_with_robot        = (EditText)           view.findViewById(R.id.user_chat_with_robot);
        mMessagesView               = (RecyclerView)       view.findViewById(R.id.messages);
        revealView                  = (CircularRevealView) view.findViewById(R.id.reveal);
        //@formatter:on

        ...

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        Log.e("DISMISS", "  CLICKED");
    }

    public interface OnCloseSlidingLayer {
        void onClose();
    }

    public static void setOnCloseSlidingLayer(OnCloseSlidingLayer l) {
        onCloseSlidingLayer = l;
    }
}
```

`onDismiss` from fragment work fine on any activity, but it doesnt work on this fragment

Comment: Try moving super.onDismiss(dialog) to the end of the method instead of the start - see if that changes anything.

Comment: @jt-gilkeson doesnt work sir

Comment: Fragments aren't activities, so calling getActivity in the dialog shouldn't return your FragmentRobotAssisstant fragment. Have you made sure that the fragment's parent activity implements the OnDismissListener?

Comment: This problem redolve by define simple listener as inretface.i dont implement that on parent activity. No

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy Where are you calling `RobotDialog.show()`?

Comment: @Bryan on fragment i'm showing dialog

Comment: Can you add please your code where you are creating and showing the RobotDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jace's comment, in RobotoDialog:

```
 @Override
 public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
     final Fragment parent = getParentFragment();
     if (parent != null && parent instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {              
         ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) parent).onDismiss(dialog);
     }
     super.onDismiss(dialog);
 }
```

Comment: What context are you using to show the dialog?  FragmentRobotAssisstant with getFragmentManager() ? or the parent activity?  If you want to be able to handle the onDismiss in the FragmentRobotAssisstant  you must show the RobotFragment with getFragmentManager context, not the activity's context.